# Google Slides scripts. To copy across when the slides are copied

Tags: google-apps-script

I've made a script on  a Google Slides, that will then be added to an assignment on Google Classroom. When students access the assignment, Classroom the makes copies for the student(s). I need the script to be copied across too so that it works on individual students work/slides. Is this possible?

Currently the script does not seem to copy across.